# How to create new project within Xampp?

Tags: apache2, xampp

I was wondering how you can create a new folder so when I type `localhost/folder`, it will read the files within the folder.

I don't know where to find the folder to put it.

Comment: apache normally stores it's web content under the **/var/www/** folder so you can add a folder there as root and go to **localhost:80/foldername/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I simply did, was to find out the working directory for the apache, on the config file. Simple as that.